# how to add and remove input textbox in asp.net master page

Tags: javascript, html, css, webforms

*trying to add and remove input textbox for a form cv but it does not work.
by using asp.net in master page. when I click in icon doesn't work. it will be a textbox and icon "+" to add .. when click in the icon it give the same textbox input in. and other icon to remove the other textbox..

*I'm not use MVC..* 
if there is other way to code? I will appreciate this.

**this is my code:**
`enter code here`
this is my code (java script+css+html)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {

        if (counter > 10) {
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
        }

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('span'))
            .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

        newTextBoxDiv.after().aspx('Textbox' + counter +
            '<input type="text" name="courseName' + counter +
            '" id="courseId' + counter + '" value="" >');

        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#course");


        counter++;
    });

    $("#removeButton").click(function () {
        if (counter == 1) {
            alert("No more textbox to remove");
            return false;
        }

        counter--;

        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

    });

    $("#sumbitcvId").click(function () {

        var msg = '';
        for (i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
            msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
        }
        alert(msg);
    });
});
```

```css
.coursecv,.mosdcv {
    font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 27.5%;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="course">
            <div>
          

            <h1>course</h1>
        

            </div>
        <span id="TextBoxDiv">
        
         <asp:TextBox ID="courseId" runat="server" name="courseName" type="Text" placeholder="course name" CssClass="coursecv" value="" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
        </span>
        <span>
        <asp:TextBox ID="mosdId" runat="server" name="mosdName" type="Text" placeholder="Corporation" CssClass="mosdcv" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
        </span>
        

</div>

            <div Id="ADD"  style="margin-left:87%;color: #3c6bf4;font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;font-size: 17px;">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addButton" title="Add field"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
                         <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="removeButton" title="Remove field"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></a>


                
            
</div>
```

Comment: Can you check whether you're getting any script errors?

Comment: @Anuraj It dosen't give me an error just not working when I into to the page

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using class names to identify the fields in JQuery - you should use the dot(.) as the identifier than hash (#). Hash is used to identifying elements using Id.

```
$(".addButton").click(function () {

    if (counter > 10) {
        alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
        return false;
    }

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('span'))
        .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().append('Textbox' + counter +
        '<input type="text" name="courseName' + counter +
        '" id="courseId' + counter + '" value="" >');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#course");


    counter++;
});
```

The above code will trigger the click action and will add text boxes.